# Pre Process the dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset df with the following entries..

```
Date         Count
19/09/2019   1491
20/09/2019   1692
21/09/2019   1753
22/09/2019   1817
23/09/2019   1986
24/09/2019   2022
25/09/2019   2343
26/09/2019   2277
27/09/2019   2343
28/09/2019   2599
29/09/2019   2622
30/09/2019   2704
01/10/2019   2903
02/10/2019   3035
03/10/2019   3099
04/10/2019   3204
05/10/2019   3285
```

I am actually trying to analyse the dataset using the ARIMA. I am trying to follow the steps mentioned in the post

> https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/

But I am facing a few issues with the same.

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

autocorrelation_plot(series)
pyplot.show()
```

I am trying to get the autocorrelation_plot but I am getting the following error :

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Also,

when I am trying to get the values for count using :

```
X = df.values
```

it is returning me as a tupled pair

```
array([['19/09/2019', 1491],
       ['20/09/2019', 1692],
       ['21/09/2019', 1753],
       ['22/09/2019', 1817],
       ['23/09/2019', 1986],
       ['24/09/2019', 2022],
       ['25/09/2019', 2343],
       ['26/09/2019', 2277],
       ['27/09/2019', 2343],
```

instead of just the count. Can anyone suggest what is it that I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Which variable is `series`? Which is `df`? Please provide some clarity

Answer (score 0):

Your first step is create `TimeSeries`, so use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
series = df.set_index('Date')['Count']
```

---

```
print (series)
Date
2019-09-19    1491
2019-09-20    1692
2019-09-21    1753
2019-09-22    1817
2019-09-23    1986
2019-09-24    2022
2019-09-25    2343
2019-09-26    2277
2019-09-27    2343
2019-09-28    2599
2019-09-29    2622
2019-09-30    2704
2019-10-01    2903
2019-10-02    3035
2019-10-03    3099
2019-10-04    3204
2019-10-05    3285
Name: Count, dtype: int64

print (series.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2019-09-19', '2019-09-20', '2019-09-21', '2019-09-22',
               '2019-09-23', '2019-09-24', '2019-09-25', '2019-09-26',
               '2019-09-27', '2019-09-28', '2019-09-29', '2019-09-30',
               '2019-10-01', '2019-10-02', '2019-10-03', '2019-10-04',
               '2019-10-05'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', freq=None)
```